# How can i enable sharepoint custom search scope in code?

Tags: search-scope

I want to enable custom scopes in sharepoint in code.
[image]

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site shows you how to do it: http://www.sharepointconfig.com/2011/04/creating-sharepoint-2010-search-scopes-programmatically/

You'll want to look into the QueryManager class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee588559.aspx

This may help too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557874.aspx

Comment: Thanks for tips. But i dont get it how actually to enable just custom scopes like sharepoint do this with this check box...